# Create multiple Jquery dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am trying to create multiple dialog box and some how i am not able to understand how to create those dialog boxes.

I have `DIV's` for each dialog box which has a message for every action. Basically if user check the `CheckBox` then dialog appears saying that you want to confirm this action. And after some time if user again uncheck that `CheckBox` then another dialog appears with the diff message. Please help me with this one.

Here is what i have got so far.

===============

### HTML

```
<div id="dialog-isReceived" title="Mark as Received?">
    Are you sure you want to mark this order as "Received"? <br />
    The customer will receive an email confirming their order is ready for collection.
</div>
<div id="dialog-notReceived" title="Mark as Not Received?">
    Are you sure you want to mark this order as "Not Received"? <br />
</div>
```

---

## Jquery

```
var isReceivedCheckBox = $('.isReceivedCheckBox input[type=checkbox]');
var dialogId; //trying to pass the Id of the div dynamically BUT not working 
var result;
$(document).ready(function () {
$(dialogId).dialog(
  {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
              "Confirm": function () {
                    result = true;
              },
              Cancel: function () {
                    result = false;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
              }
        },
  });
});
```

=====================

## CODE that i want to execute

```
$(document).on("change",isReceivedCheckBox, function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
if (checked) {
  dialogId = "'#dialog-isReceived'"; //setting the DIV ID here and hoping that dialog will appears.
  $(dialogId).dialog('open');
  if(!result)
        $(this).attr("checked", false); // if user clicks cancel on dialog then do not check the checkbox
} else {
    dialogId = "'#dialog-notReceived'";
    $(dialogId).dialog('open');
  if(!result)
        $(this).attr("checked", true); //if user clicks cancel on dialog then do not uncheck the checkbox because it was checked previously
}
});
```

the problem here is dialog never appears because when the page loads all my div are are visible as i am not able to set the `dialogID` variable on page load. Also i have atleast 5 dialogs on this page doing same functionality. If you can suggest better approach or tell me what i am doing wrong here would be great and appreciated.

thanks,
Milan P

Comment: Why dont you keep a single div and a dialog and change the content at dynamically ?

Comment: Ahhh.. BUT i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Just create a dialog and as per your condition set the content using $( "#id_of your_dialog" ).html("THE CONTENT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible problem with your approach is that jQuery dialog is async, this means that the conditional

```
if(!result)
```

will be evaluated long before your user has time to confirm or cancel the dialog. If what you want is to mimic the behavior of the javascript confirm using dialogs youll need to use jQuery Deferred object. Also, i would suggest creating and destroying the dialog as needed, something like:

```
function confirmDialog(msg) {
    var dialog = $("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $(dialog).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'Confirm': function() {
                def.resolve();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                def.reject();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            if (def.state() === "pending") {
                def.reject(); // Make sure unanswered dialog rejects
            }

            $( this ).remove();
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
confirmDialog("are your sure?").done(function() {
    // He/She said yes
}).fail(function() {
    // He/She said no
});
```

Read more on jQuery Deferred here http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fGQTj/

Edit: fixed code, added fiddle

Comment: Looks like you hit the right rock here... let me try this and i will also have a look at the link you provided for more info. +1 for dynamically generating the DIV's... Ohhhh i love Jquery...#

Comment: Fixed the missing "function ()" on close, added a fiddle.

Comment: Hi @cernunnos: i have tried this BUt somehow its not working. can you see this Fiddle for me please, Also i have to click twice on button to close the dialog. http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/ka8W8/

Comment: @patel.milanb the jquery on that fiddle was getting an exception on the toLowerCase function, fixed your fiddle with some minor improvements (this.checked instead of $(this).is(":checked")): http://jsfiddle.net/ka8W8/5/  PS: You may want to try to figure out why your fiddle account was having trouble with the toLowerCase javascript function :)

Comment: yes...i also got that error on my dev machine. I thought its a Jquery error and i updated the jquery vesrion. still getting the error. will look at your fiddle. thanks for your time.

Comment: the Fiddle you provided is working fine except i want to uncheck the checkbox when user click the checkbox and then on dialog user select Cancel Button. right now its still check the checkbox and making the cancel button completely useless.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't read the confirm messages, try http://jsfiddle.net/ka8W8/10/  The most important change is the "var that = this" outside of the dialog, since inside the context changes ("this" will no longer refer to the checkbox). Note that you can remove the whole .done() block if you don't need it.

Comment: Man you are awesome... you made my day... working perfect on Fiddle. lets try on my dev machine... will give you feedback in sometime..

Comment: May help debug: the problem u had on you dev machine can be fixed using the same "var that=this" approach of the last fiddle. The undefined toLowerCase was being thrown because $(this).is(":checked") tried to lowercase an "undefined".

Comment: everything is working great except when user clicks on checkbox instead of waiting for the user input which is YES or NO, its fires YES and modifying the database value. and if on dialog i click NO. the database record is already updated with yes. dont know why this is happening, i copied exactly from your Fiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24774/discussion-between-patel-milanb-and-cernunnos)

Comment: its working fine in Fiddle. BUt not in my machine http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/ka8W8/